# SCIP 7.0.3 installing using cmake on macOS TBB error

Tags: scip

I am trying to build the SCIP 7.0.3 opt suite on my Mac machine and I facing some issues.

I am using CMake to generate the make Makefile and once I type `make`, I am failing at the linking step. I am attaching the log here

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target papilolib
[100%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libpapilo.dylib
ld: warning: object file (../libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
ld: warning: object file (../libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
ld: warning: object file (../libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
ld: warning: object file (../libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
ld: warning: object file (../libclusol.a(lusol7b.f.o)) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tbb::interface5::internal::task_base::destroy(tbb::task&)", referenced from:
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(), papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(), papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()>(double const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'() const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(), papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(), papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()>(double const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'() const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda'(), papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda0'()>(double const&, papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda1'(), papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda2'(), papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda3'(), papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda4'(), papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda5'()>(double const&, papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda1'() const&, papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda2'() const&, papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda3'() const&, papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda4'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::Problem<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda'(), papilo::Problem<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda0'(), papilo::Problem<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda1'()>(double const&, papilo::Problem<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda'() const&, papilo::Problem<double>::compress(bool)::'lambda0'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      
      void tbb::interface9::internal::dynamic_grainsize_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type> >::work_balance<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::execute<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      ...
  "tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::internal_capacity() const", referenced from:
      papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      papilo::Sparsify<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::execute<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::dynamic_grainsize_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type> >::work_balance<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::execute<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::dynamic_grainsize_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type> >::work_balance<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::execute<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::dynamic_grainsize_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type> >::work_balance<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::execute<tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>, tbb::blocked_range<int> >(double&, tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      ...
  "tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const", referenced from:
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Sparsify<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::Sparsify<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      ...
  "tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(), papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(), papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()>(double const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'() const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      void tbb::parallel_invoke<papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(), papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(), papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()>(double const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'() const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'() const&, tbb::task_group_context&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::computeColHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::Probing<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, papilo::DominatedCols<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&) const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in papilolib.cpp.o
      ...
  "typeinfo for tbb::task", referenced from:
      typeinfo for tbb::empty_task in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::internal::function_invoker<papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()> in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::internal::function_invoker<papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda0'()> in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::computeRowHashes(papilo::ConstraintMatrix<double> const&, unsigned int*)::'lambda'(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&), tbb::auto_partitioner const> in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::interface9::internal::flag_task in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::internal::function_invoker<papilo::ParallelRowDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda'()> in papilolib.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::internal::function_invoker<papilo::ParallelColDetection<double>::execute(papilo::Problem<double> const&, papilo::ProblemUpdate<double> const&, papilo::Num<double> const&, papilo::Reductions<double>&)::'lambda1'()> in papilolib.cpp.o
      ...
  "__gfortran_generate_error", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1rec in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu6chk.constprop.0 in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
  "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1rec in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu6chk.constprop.0 in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu6prt_ in libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)
      _lu8mod_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      _lu8adc_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      ...
  "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1rec in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu6chk.constprop.0 in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu6prt_ in libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)
      _lu8mod_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      _lu8adc_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      ...
  "__gfortran_stop_string", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
  "__gfortran_transfer_array_write", referenced from:
      _lu6prt_ in libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)
  "__gfortran_transfer_character_write", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu6chk.constprop.0 in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu7rnk_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      _lu6chk_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      _lu1fad_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      _lu1fac_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      ...
  "__gfortran_transfer_integer_write", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1rec in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu6chk.constprop.0 in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu6prt_ in libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)
      _lu8mod_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      _lu8adc_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      ...
  "__gfortran_transfer_logical_write", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1rec in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu1rec_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
  "__gfortran_transfer_real_write", referenced from:
      ___lusol_MOD_lu8rpc in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      ___lusol_MOD_lu1fac in libclusol.a(lusol.f90.o)
      _lu6prt_ in libclusol.a(lusol6b.f.o)
      _lu8adc_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      _lu8adr_ in libclusol.a(lusol8b.f.o)
      _lu1fad_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      _lu1fac_ in libclusol.a(lusol_util.f.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libpapilo.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [papilo/binaries/CMakeFiles/papilolib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed TBB on my Mac using the command `brew install tbb`

The above log has to be trimmed in the middle as I am unable to paste the full log.

For full log https://pastebin.com/p7YL4161

edit: I am using macOS latest version and my `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DIPOPT=off ..`

```
-- Build type: Release
SoPlex with Boost CPP multiprecision libraries.
-- Could NOT find Quadmath (missing: Quadmath_LIBRARY Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.58.0") found components: program_options 
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0")  
-- Could NOT find Quadmath (missing: Quadmath_LIBRARY Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Git hash: e567fef
-- Build shared libraries: ON
-- Build type: Release
-- Finding ZLIB
-- Finding ZLIB - found
-- Finding Readline
-- Finding Readline - found
-- Finding GMP
-- Finding GMP - found
-- Finding PAPILO
-- Finding PAPILO - found
-- Finding Solver "spx"
-- Finding Soplex
-- Finding SOPLEX - found
-- Support CLP: OFF
-- Support CPLEX: OFF
-- Support GLOP: OFF
-- Support GUROBI: OFF
-- Support XPRESS: OFF
-- Support MOSEK: OFF
-- Support QSO: OFF
-- Finding symmetry computation program "bliss"
-- Finding BLISS
-- Could NOT find BLISS (missing: BLISS_INCLUDE_DIR BLISS_INCLUDE_DIRS BLISS_LIBRARIES BLISS_DEFINITIONS) 
-- Finding BLISS - not found
-- CodeCoverage: OFF
-- Finding ZIMPL
-- Finding ZIMPL - found
-- Support IPOPT: OFF
-- Support WORHP: OFF
-- Looking for FE_DOWNWARD
-- Looking for FE_DOWNWARD - found
-- Finding CRITERION
-- Could NOT find CRITERION (missing: CRITERION_LIBRARY CRITERION_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Finding CRITERION - not found
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Success
-- Could NOT find CRITERION (missing: CRITERION_LIBRARY CRITERION_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Support AMPL: OFF
-- Build shared libraries: ON
-- Build type: Release
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Found GSL: /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.6/include (found suitable version "2.6", minimum required is "2.0") 
-- Could NOT find CLIQUER (missing: CLIQUER_INCLUDE_DIRS CLIQUER_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find BLISS (missing: BLISS_INCLUDE_DIR BLISS_INCLUDE_DIRS BLISS_LIBRARIES BLISS_DEFINITIONS) 
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0") found components: iostreams serialization program_options 
-- Performing Test PAPILO_USE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS_WITH_ZLIB
-- Performing Test PAPILO_USE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS_WITH_ZLIB - Success
-- Performing Test PAPILO_USE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS_WITH_BZIP2
-- Performing Test PAPILO_USE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS_WITH_BZIP2 - Success
-- Linking solvers: SCIP;SoPlex
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Threads
 * BLAS
 * PkgConfig
 * GSL (required version >= 2.0)

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * BISON
 * FLEX
 * TBB
 * Readline
 * PAPILO
 * ZIMPL
 * ZLIB
 * GMP
 * SCIP
 * SOPLEX
 * boost_headers (required version == 1.76.0)
 * Boost

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * Quadmath
 * CRITERION
 * CLIQUER
 * HMETIS
 * BLISS

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/username/Downloads/scipoptsuite-7.0.3/build
```

Answer (score 2):

the compile fails because there is a internal function missing in your tbb lib.

TBB made a switch from tbb -> oneTBB base on the oneapi. We currently don't support the oneTBB but are working on that.

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tbb Tbb links to oneTBB so you need to install tbb@2020 (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tbb@2020).

Maybe you need to remove or unlink tbb before that to get the build running. Remember to delete the build directory before trying to recompile due to caching issues.

Could you please try that and then report if it worked.

Philipp

Comment: I am having some issues as the CmakeLists.txt provided with SCIP can not find tbb@2020. I have to wrangle something I guess.

Comment: that is weird.. I will take a look own our testmac to see if I see anthing weird going on with tbb@2020.

Comment: some additional logs  building TBB is failing (line 5).  https://pastebin.com/JPqaDAXH